# Does something like assertHTMLEquals exist for unit testing

Tags: java, html, junit

In my test I check:

```
assertEquals("<div class=\"action-button\" title=\"actionButton\">"</div>", result);
```

If someone changes the html (`result`), putting there SPACE, the HTML still valid, but my test would fail.

Is there some way to compare two html pieces if those are equal as HTML. Like `assertHTMLEquals`

---

XML UNIT says that this two lines are equal:

string1:

```
<ldapConfigurations>
<ldap tenantid="" active="false">
</ldap>
</ldapConfigurations>
```

string2:

```
<ldapConfigurations>
<ldapdd tenantid="" active="false">
</ldap>
</ldapConfigurations>
```

but they are not, as you can see. (see: `ldapdd` )

Comment: Are you looking for an HTML validator or to check if two `String`s (that happen to have HTML) are equal?

Comment: checking if two Strings (that happen to have HTML) are equal

Comment: Your worry is that something like `<div class="blah"/>` is equivalent to `<div class = "blah"/>` but not equal to it?

Comment: Can you show your code for how you're passing those in?  I know this would fail for me.

Answer (score 4):

This won't necessarily work for your case, but if your HTML happens to be valid XML it will.  You can use this tool called [xmlunit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/).  With it, you can write an assert method that looks like this:

```
public static void assertXMLEqual(Reader reader, String xml) {
    try {
        XMLAssert.assertXMLEqual(reader, new StringReader(xml));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        XMLAssert.fail();
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, maybe there's some other tool out there meant for HTML comparisons.  And if that doesn't work, you may want to end up using a library like jtagsoup (or whatever) and comparing if all the fields it parses are equal.

Comment: html in most cases is xml, so it might help.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve **malformed HTML asserting** throught the `TolerantSaxDocumentBuilder` utility of [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

```
TolerantSaxDocumentBuilder tolerantSaxDocumentBuilder =
                         new TolerantSaxDocumentBuilder(XMLUnit.newTestParser());
HTMLDocumentBuilder htmlDocumentBuilder =
                         new HTMLDocumentBuilder(tolerantSaxDocumentBuilder);
XMLAssert.assertXMLEqual(htmlDocumentBuilder.parse(expectedHTML),
                         htmlDocumentBuilder.parse(actualHTML));
```

To support badly formed HTML (such as elements without closing tags - unthinkable in XML), you must make use of an additional document builder, the `TolerantSaxDocumentBuilder`, along with the `HTMLDocumentBuilder` (this one will allow asserting on web pages). After that, assert the documents as usual.

#### Working code example:

```
public class TestHTML {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String result = "<div             class=\"action-button\"                title=\"actionButton\">            </div>";
        assertHTMLEquals("<div class=\"action-button\" title=\"actionButton\"></div>", result); // ok!

        // notice it is badly formed
        String expectedHtml = "<html><title>Page Title</title>"         
                + "<body><h1>Heads<ul>"
                + "<li id='1'>Some Item<li id='2'>Another item";

        String actualMalformedHTML = expectedHtml.replace(" ", "     "); // just added some spaces, wont matter
        assertHTMLEquals(expectedHtml, actualMalformedHTML); // ok!

        actualMalformedHTML = actualMalformedHTML.replace("Heads", "Tails");
        assertHTMLEquals(expectedHtml, actualMalformedHTML); // assertion fails
    }

    public static void assertHTMLEquals(String expectedHTML, String actualHTML) throws Exception {
        TolerantSaxDocumentBuilder tolerantSaxDocumentBuilder = new TolerantSaxDocumentBuilder(XMLUnit.newTestParser());
        HTMLDocumentBuilder htmlDocumentBuilder = new HTMLDocumentBuilder(tolerantSaxDocumentBuilder);
        XMLAssert.assertXMLEqual(htmlDocumentBuilder.parse(expectedHTML), htmlDocumentBuilder.parse(actualHTML));
    }
}
```

Notice that XML functions, such as XPath, will be available to your HTML document as well.

If using Maven, add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'd say that's happening because those aren't standard HTML tags (it's a `HTMLDocumentBuilder`). Try putting `"<html><body>"` before both strings and `"</body></html>"` after both.

Comment: @ses It works here (the method in the answer) after I add those to the strings.

Comment: @ses Actually, a simple `"<body>"` (or any other HTML element, like `"<span></span>"`) at the beginning (or middle) of the strings is enough to hint the document builder to build a HTML. If you'll have to test snippets like that a lot, I think you can safely add something like that at the beginning of every test string.

Comment: What was the veredict on this?